# A WP Query for Posts and Pages but only returns 1 posts/pages

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to create a wp query that goes through posts and pages and only returns one (the most recent, being a post or a page). So far, I have this:

```
$conteudo_complexo = new WP_Query(array(
   'post_type'        => array('post', 'page'),
   'posts_per_page'   => 1,
   'orderby'          => 'date',
   'order'            => 'DESC',
   'meta_key'         => 'tipo_de_destaque_homepage',
   'meta_value'       => 'topoeditorial'
));
```

This is returning multiple pages...

What I'm looking for is something like: go through posts and pages and return only one post or page with that `meta_value`, whichever is the most recent one.

Note: The `meta_key` and `meta_value` is for custom fields.

Comment: At a quick glance I’m not seeing anything wrong, can you show how you are using this which shows the multiple items? Also, although not wrong, I personally tend to steer people to [`get_posts()` over dedicated queries](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/1755).

Comment: Thank you! That was it! I've changed to get_posts( array( .... and now it works :)